# How to comprehend "The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables when using volatile keyword"?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

From book "Java Concurrency in Practice" page 26:

You can use volatile variables only when all the following criteria are met:

- Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value, or you can ensure that only a single thread ever updates the value;
- The variabledoes not participate in invariants with other state variables; and
- Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed.

How to comprehend "*The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables when using volatile keyword*"?

Comment: Some more context would be useful, otherwise I would be just guessing what it could mean.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the context now

Comment: In my book it is 39 page

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simple definition of "invariant": *a condition that is always true during the lifetime of an object*.

> Volatile variables do not share the atomicity features of `synchronized` blocks.

That's why you can't use them within a class that has invariants that relate multiple variables.

For example imagine you have a `class` to model a time interval described by two variables: `start` and `end`. An invariant condition may be that `start` is always less or equal than `end`. If both variables (just as example) are declared as volatile then you can rely on visibility features of `volatile` but you can't be sure that during a change that involves both variables the invariant is always satisfied. Think:

```
public void setInterval(Date newStart, Date newEnd)
{
 // Check if inputs are correct

 // Here the object state is valid
 start = newStart;

 // If another thread accesses this object now it will
 // see an invalid state because start could be greater than end

 end = newEnd;
 // Here the object state is valid again
}
```

In this case you can be sure that the change is visible to every thread but in the middle of the two instructions the object state could be not valid. Because it can be accessed by other threads (remember this is a simple case so it's possible but not likely) then the invariant condition "start < end" could be broken.

That's why the use of volatile is somehow discouraged outside a (small) set of well defined patterns. A volatile variable should be used only if these conditions are satisfied:

- The variable isn't involved in invariants related to other variables (for the reason explained above).
- The value to write on the variable does not depend on its current value.

For example the expression `int a = i++;` isn't atomic then it's not - strictly speaking - thread-safe because it'll be *rewritten* with something like this:

```
int temp = i;
i = i + 1;
int a = temp;
```

To make it *atomic* from a thread point of view you can imagine a class like this:

```
public class MyAtomicInteger
{
  public synchronized increment()
  {
    x = x + 1;
  }

  private int x;
}
```

Of course it exists a true implementation of this `AtomicInteger` and it's part of the package [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), it provides some simple basic routines for lock-free concurrent programming.

Comment: There's an error: it's not `i = i + 1` but `i = temp + 1` in your `i` increment sample, otherwise leading to infinite substatements since `i = i + 1` is the same as `i++` operation.

Comment: @Mik378 before the increment "i == temp" so "i = i + 1" is equivalent to "i = temp + 1". It's how "++" is expanded not "+" then "i + 1" won't be expanded again

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti spent 2 days trying to break down invariants - learned math functions, oracle documentation and many other sources. Useless. Just read your example you provided. It was brilliant!

Comment: @RachaelO'James happy to be useful! It's kind of surprising though, (I thought) the `Interval` thing was a go-to example to explain this concept

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yeah Oracle says invariants are about conditions and relations. What relations? What conditions? it doesn't say anything. That's ok I can google. I'm googling and I see Math definition of invariants. And then you got a question: what? relations? With the example you provided I understood that those are relations between mutable variables that multithreading should not affect.